# Смена хостинга

Tags: modx, cms, хостинг

Здравствуйте!
Второй день воюю с переносом ModX с одного выделенного сервера на другой. Пробовал переносить modX по мануалу на оф. сайте, но не выходит. Суть проблемы: переношу все файлы и папки, меняю пути в конфигурационных файлах, загружаю дамп бд, в итоге сайт отображается, но не отображаются шаблоны, также при переходе в админку вообще ничего не отображается, просто белый экран (то есть даже нет возможности ввести логин/пароль).  
В логах апача ошибок нет.  
В чем может быть проблема? В каком направлении смотреть?

**UPD:**

Вообщем есть немного больше информации, получилось подключить шаблоны и админку.
В чем суть, сайт переносится на bitnami, до этого, на старом хостинге сайт был доступен по адресу **mysite.ru**, теперь же, так как на bitnami есть установленные приложения, необходимо чтобы данный сайт был доступен по адресу **example.ru/mysite**.
Таким образом я добавляю в корень сайта конфигурационный файл со следующим кодом:

```
Alias /mysite/ "/srv/www/mysite/public_html/"
Alias /mysite "/srv/www/mysite/public_html/"

<Directory "/srv/www/mysite/public_html">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

При этом в httpd.conf включаю этот файл. Таким образом и происходят вышеописанные проблемы.
Но если я добавляю конфиг вместо кода выше следующий код:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/mysite/public_html"
    ServerName example.ru
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/srv/www/mysite/public_html">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

То все работает, но соответственно не работает другое приложение, которое ссылается на этот адрес. Вопрос: что нужно поправить, чтобы корректно отображался сайт по адресу **example.ru/mysite**?
Возможно объяснил как-то по тарабарски, но может у кого есть идеи? сейчас буду пробовать .htaccess править, может в нем причина?

Comment: Где-то на новом сервере у файлов послетали  права и владелец.

Comment: ставил на на каталог и подкаталоги права 777 (через sudo chmod -R 777 /mypath), не помогло(

Comment: chown -R /mypath new-user-name

Comment: Владельца еще изначально ставил на папку, чтобы туда можно было писать, сейчас поменял, но все равно не помогает, все-таки склоняюсь к ошибки в путях, так как после корректировки httpd.conf отображаться стал корректно(example.ru), но не по тому адресу(надо example.ru/mysite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую ответить на свой вопрос, чтобы поставить какую-то точку.
Проблема все-таки была с доменом, на домен типа example.ru/mysite это приложение так и не удалось подключить, но без проблем удалось подключить на example.ru (т.к у нас 2 домена второго уровня, то удалось все сделать как надо).
По поводу белого экрана и шаблонов тоже все поправилось, но далее когда менял директорию приложения на сервере админка опять отказалась работать (белый экран), тут действительно проблема была в правах, а именно скорее всего в правах на папку /core/cache/.